# Tableau is adding numbers that appear more than once. How can i fix this?

Tags: excel, csv, tableau-api

I am working with a data set that has numbers that appear more than once and Tableau is automatically adding them together. For exanple, the numbers 45 and 50 appears twice in my data set so when i try making a bar graph(or any other graph for that matter) it is automatically addind them together. How can i fix this?

Comment: Hi pikProgram, can you please upload an example of the data and bar graph so that people can help you answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number field you have mentioned to dimension.

> Right click on the number pill -> Convert to dimension

Tableau slice the data once you convert the type, Instead of  aggregation